# Bootstrap Collapse columns not aligning properly on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating two separate keyword search options using Bootstrap collapse. The alignment of the collapse items look correct until you click, "Keyword Search." When the collapse is open on "Keyword Search," then the "Affiliation Search" collapse button moves to the right corner of the page. How do I make it so that the second bootstrap collapse button stays below the first bootstrap collapse button?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#keyword-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="keyword-search">
  <h4>Search by Keyword</h4>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="keyword-search">
  <div class="well">
    <ul>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="ag-health" id="ag-health"/> Agricultural Health</label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="animal-health" id="animal-health"/> Animal Health </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="a-r" id="a-r"/> Antimicrobial Resistance </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="conservation" id="conservation" /> Conservation </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="economics" id="economics"/> Economics </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="entomology" id="entomology"/> Entomology </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="epidemiology" id="epidemiology"/> Epidemiology </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="food-safety" id="food-safety"/> Food Safety </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="history" id="history"/> History </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="human-health" id="human-health"/> Human Health</label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="infectious-diseases" id="infectious-diseases"/> Infectious Diseases </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="outreach" id="outreach"/> Outreach </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="science-communication" id="science-communication"/> Science Communication </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="soil-health" id="soil-health"/> Soil Health </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="surveillance" id="surveillance"/> Surveillance </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="vet-med" id="vet-med"/> Veterinary Medicine </label>
      <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" value="water-quality" id="water-quality"/> Water Quality </label>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#affiliation-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="affiliation-search">
  <h4>Search by Affiliation</h4>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="affiliation-search">
  <div class="well">
    <ul>
      <form>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="ch-foundation" id="ch-foundation"/> Claire M Hubbard Foundation</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="creighton" id="creighton"/> Creighton University</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="wff" id="wff"/> Daugherty Water for Food Global Institute</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="doane" id="doane"/> Doane University</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="douglas-co-hd" id="douglas-co-hd"/> Douglas County Health Department</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="lancaster-hd" id="lancaster-hd"/> Lincoln-Lancaster County Health Department</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="lincoln-zoo" id="lincoln-zoo"/> Lincoln Children's Zoo</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="master-naturalist" id="master-naturalist"/> Master Naturalist</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nature-con" id="nature-con"/> The Nature Conservancy in Nebraska</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nedeq" id="nedeq"/> Nebraska Department of Environmental Quality</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nedhhs" id="nedhhs"/> Nebraska Department of Health and Human Services</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="extension" id="extension"/> Nebraska Extension</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="game-parks" id="game-parks"/> Nebraska Game and Parks Commission</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="omaha-zoo" id="omaha-zoo"/> Omaha's Henry Doorly Zoo and Aquarium</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="pha" id="pha"/> Public Health Association of Nebraska</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="usda" id="usda"/> United States Department of Agriculture</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="usgs" id="usgs"/> United States Geological Survey</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unk" id="unk"/> University of Nebraska-Kearney</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unl" id="unl"/> University of Nebraska-Lincoln</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unmc" id="unmc"/> University of Nebraska Medical Center</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="uno" id="uno"/> University of Nebraska-Omaha</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="water-center" id="water-center"/> University of Nebraska Water Center</label>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a link to a codepen example! https://codepen.io/aahmed2/pen/KQaXNy?editors=1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `col-md-*` to `col-sm-*`/`col-xs-*`, it will stop misalignment.
But the problem you are mentioning about, **Affiliation Search** moving to right, I don't see that happen.

It's right below the first dropdown.

Correct me, if I'm not understanding your question.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#keyword-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="keyword-search">
  <h4>Search by Keyword</h4>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="keyword-search">
  <div class="well">
    <ul class="row">
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="ag-health" id="ag-health"/> Agricultural Health</label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="animal-health" id="animal-health"/> Animal Health </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="a-r" id="a-r"/> Antimicrobial Resistance </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="conservation" id="conservation" /> Conservation </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="economics" id="economics"/> Economics </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="entomology" id="entomology"/> Entomology </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="epidemiology" id="epidemiology"/> Epidemiology </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="food-safety" id="food-safety"/> Food Safety </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="history" id="history"/> History </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="human-health" id="human-health"/> Human Health</label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="infectious-diseases" id="infectious-diseases"/> Infectious Diseases </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="outreach" id="outreach"/> Outreach </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="science-communication" id="science-communication"/> Science Communication </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="soil-health" id="soil-health"/> Soil Health </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="surveillance" id="surveillance"/> Surveillance </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="vet-med" id="vet-med"/> Veterinary Medicine </label>
      <label class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" value="water-quality" id="water-quality"/> Water Quality </label>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#affiliation-search" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="affiliation-search">
  <h4>Search by Affiliation</h4>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="affiliation-search">
  <div class="well">
    <ul class="row">
      <form>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="ch-foundation" id="ch-foundation"/> Claire M Hubbard Foundation</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="creighton" id="creighton"/> Creighton University</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="wff" id="wff"/> Daugherty Water for Food Global Institute</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="doane" id="doane"/> Doane University</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="douglas-co-hd" id="douglas-co-hd"/> Douglas County Health Department</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="lancaster-hd" id="lancaster-hd"/> Lincoln-Lancaster County Health Department</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="lincoln-zoo" id="lincoln-zoo"/> Lincoln Children's Zoo</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="master-naturalist" id="master-naturalist"/> Master Naturalist</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nature-con" id="nature-con"/> The Nature Conservancy in Nebraska</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nedeq" id="nedeq"/> Nebraska Department of Environmental Quality</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="nedhhs" id="nedhhs"/> Nebraska Department of Health and Human Services</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="extension" id="extension"/> Nebraska Extension</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="game-parks" id="game-parks"/> Nebraska Game and Parks Commission</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="omaha-zoo" id="omaha-zoo"/> Omaha's Henry Doorly Zoo and Aquarium</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="pha" id="pha"/> Public Health Association of Nebraska</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="usda" id="usda"/> United States Department of Agriculture</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="usgs" id="usgs"/> United States Geological Survey</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unk" id="unk"/> University of Nebraska-Kearney</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unl" id="unl"/> University of Nebraska-Lincoln</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="unmc" id="unmc"/> University of Nebraska Medical Center</label>
        <label class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="uno" id="uno"/> University of Nebraska-Omaha</label>
        <label class="col-md-6"><input type="checkbox" value="water-center" id="water-center"/> University of Nebraska Water Center</label>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! My problem I think was that I did not have my columns nested inside of a row. Thanks so much